# Is Lp space complete with this norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $E$ be a measurable set of finite measure and $1\leq a<b<\infty$.
Consider the $L^b(E)$ space normed by $L^a$ norm.
Is this space a Banach space?

I think this is wrong, so I tried to find a counterexample but it is hard to find one...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $L^b(E)$ is complete under the $L^a$ norm. Then by the Banach isomorphism theorem, there would be a constant $C$ such that for any $f\in L^b(E)$, $\lVert f\rVert_b\leqslant C\lVert f\Vert_a$. In particular, if $f=\chi_A$ for $A\subset E$ measurable, we would get $\mu(A)^{1/b-1/a}\leqslant C$, hence 
$$\inf_{A:\mu(A)>0}\mu(A)>0.$$
This condition implies that, together with finiteness of the measure space, that 
$E$ is a finite union of atoms and in this case, $L^b(E)$ is finite dimensional.

Conclusion: $L^b(E)$ is complete under the $L^a$ norm if and only if it is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Umm...I learned only real analysis in undergraduate level.. Can you explain more easily??

Comment: Also I think inequality is wrong

Comment: If you expect an answer in undergraduate level, no problem. Maybe you could state it in the question.// Which inequality are you talking about?

Comment: I think 4th line is wrong.. b norm is larger than a norm  multiply c

Comment: I find counter example. x^(-0.5+1/n) on(0 , 1]

Comment: I agree that this inequality is wrong _in general_. However, if we assume that $L^b$ is complete under the $L^a$ norm, this inequality will be true.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo excuse me for the late question, but I stumbled across this post. How do we know that the bounded linear isomorphism between $L^b(E)$ and $L^a(E)$ is exactly the identity map ? I am missing something, I guess.